# Magento prototype - Tooltip or modal box when mouseover thumbnails from product page (Color All Module)

Tags: magento, colors, prototypejs, modal-dialog, mouseover

I have a Magento online store with Color All module. This module is great and let me put the product options images so that the customer can easily see the possibilities.
Here's an example: http://www.inusual.com.br/poltrona-yan.html

Notice that there are 4 colors thumbnails.

What I want is that when the customer rollover the mouse, the normal image (bigger size) appears, like a tooltip.
I was trying to do it with OpenTip: http://opentip.org/

The problem is that the module is encrypted and the only way to achieve this is to use Prototype to add some attributes to the DIV's.

Here's the code:

```
<div class="ca-thumbnails">
    <div>
       <img src="image.jpg">
    </div>
    <div>
       <img src="image2.jpg">
    </div>
    <div>
       <img src="image3.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

Seems like should get the 'src' from all imgs and then add attributes to the div so that the tooltip could work.

Does anyone has a clue on how to do this? 
Maybe i'm trying the hard way. lol

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

From [reading the documentation](http://www.opentip.org/documentation.html) I think you can do this:

```
$$('.ca-thumbnails img').each(function(element) {
    new Opentip(element, '<img src="' + URL_OF_LARGE_IMAGE + '">');
});
```

I don't know how you'll get the URL of the target images, perhaps that is something the makers of Color All can help with. Since you paid for their extension they are obliged to support you.